# What is the difference between SDN node and SDN enabled Base station?

Tags: sdn, 5g

I am pretty sure every network engineer would have heard about **"SDN"** i.e. **Software Defined Network**, the base of 5G network. Very soon we will be enjoying 5G in our smartphone :)

I have a doubt regarding SDN architecture. **Is the SDN node and SDN enabled Base station both are same thing?**

If they are different then please show the architecture using a diagram. I mean how they are placed and connected in space for data transmission.

Comment: We would need to know the vendor (and possibly platform) to answer this question. The problem is that the terminology is not standardized across the industry and different people use the same terms to reference different things or different terms to reference the same thing. Often you will even hear different terms when talking to a vendor’s technical resources than to its sales/marketing resources.